# Zombies attacking a village, python

Tags: python-3.x

So I am learning python and I found something to educate myself with, an assignment!

So we have 100 houses with one resident in each, one day a zombie comes along and attacks a house, the inhabitant gets infected.
Next day there are two zombies, but zombies aren't smart so they can attack an already attacked house.

How many times do the horde need to attack before all houses is infected?

This is how far I have come, the problem I got is how to handle day 2:

```
import math
import time
import sys
from random import randint

timeMeasure = [int(time.time())]
houses = 100
infected_houses = []
goal = int(sys.argv[1])

def random_house(houses):
    return randint(1, houses)
    for zombie in range(houses):
        zombie_house = random_house(houses)
        if not zombie_house in infected_houses:
            infected_houses.append(zombie_house)
            zombie += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

you can think with more then one way here 
if the day2 every zombie will atack a diffrent house then by day 7 it will be done

but if the zombies attack all the same house at the same time this will need 100 to finish it you can imagine the last day 99 zombies attacking one house and the first zombie on the list will infect the habitant

but i see you are using `random_house(houses)` in this case the random may not return everytime a diffrent number so the zombbies may attack the same house night after night and in this case it can go forever

Comment: I use the random function due to knowing which if the houses are going to be attacked and on day2 there are two zombies, they take one house each, one of them might be empty. If they hit an unattacked home day3 there can be all from 3 to 4 zombies. And so forth.

Comment: swe_mattias yes i see , but just to be clear if : random first call return 1 , and then the second call will also return 1 this mean u will attack the same house two times , and this can go on

Comment: @codergreat Yes ofc but it is random so the chance that it will happen is very very small.

Comment: yes if you see it that way we can also say that the chances that some houses wont never be attacked , thats why i said you with this way you cant predict how long it will take to end . we can maybe have a minor limit but not the max 100<x<+infinity

Comment: just to tell you that its not the code which is hard here , its just the way you see the problem